# How to update one table with data from the other, based on condition from the first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have:
[image]

The goal is to update table A with groupID from the table B, with the rule:

- if A._groupID = 1, get first B.groupID of the same subjectID and write the value to A.groupID
- if A._groupID = 2, get second B.groupID of the same subjectID and write the value to A.groupID

(Explanation: in table A groups were numbered from 1-20 for each subject, but with app upgrade it is necessary to store group data to another table and assign them a proper primary key ID (b.groupID), because of that this pairing is needed).

What I tried:

```
UPDATE A
    JOIN    B
        ON  B.subjectID = A.subjectID
SET A.groupID = B.groupID
ORDER BY A.groupID ASC
```

This results with (always writes the first result from table B):

[image]

Efficiency is not a concern because this query will be executed only once..

How to make this query work?

- the subjects also have multiple types (like lecture, exercise, practice), so group counting should take a Type into a consideration when counting.
- fiddle with working example without a Type consideration: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=172109270f3f83f8e763f7d4daffb26f
  Result:
  [image]

Can you please advise on how to modify the update query to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use analytic functions (Mysql 8) this is a breeze with `row_number()`

This works by first creating a derived table for *tableB* (another CTE could also be used). This then uses `row_number` to add numbers (in this case just 1 or 2) according to the ordering of `groupId` which matches the `_groupId` in tableA. Then it's just a simple join on both columns to assign the right value.

```
update a 
join (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by subjectid order by groupid) _groupid
  from b
)b on a.subjectid=b.subjectid and a._groupid=b._groupid
set a.groupid=b.groupid
```

[working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84c0650a91bac86a1aa002d548b62dc6)

Comment: This query works, I have no idea how, but it works :) , except maybe in some edge cases where a.groupID is null or 0, but I will sort that out.. Can you please explain a bit more what this query and used functions do? Thank you

Comment: Sure have added an additional paragraph.